# hand gesture recognition with camera video in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, gesture-recognition

I want to implement an flex application using actionscript 3: with the camera and the virture buttons(like a image) in the camera, one can move his hand to pass over the virture button field in order to fire the button. Now my solution is following this way: capture the button field in erery frame to get a bitmapdata, and calculate the gray-scale summation of the bitmapdata, if the difference between the two frames is greater than a given value, then fire
the button. Actually, it could work, but it is very sensible to the lighting condition of the background, worse, when there are more than one buttons, people often fire the button by misdike. Any better ideas ? Is there any 3rd-paty libary for this purpose ?

Answer (score 3):

You should look at http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3027

Comment: this is markable case, using a RGB wheel, but my case is markless, only using hands.

Comment: @PinkyJie, I know but I thought this demo can be usefull

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will work very well as you don't have enough information about the camera to have an accurate reading. It's probably only going to work in perfect condition. Remember that even with an infrared camera, the Kinect took a while to get the proper hardware/software combo to work. This is just a pipe dream. You need some sort of unique point of reference.

Comment: you are right, now it is very unstable, especially in the complex lighting condition. However, you konw, there are many interactive camera games on the web, how do they work?

Comment: If you point out a few, I can give an educated guess.  Most of the ones I've seen try to find an 'outline' and the user needs to be in front of a 'plain' background that doesn't change.  It then noticed movement by checking which pixels have changed from the previous image and from there can compute what the user is doing .  But even then, nothing will be 100% accurate, or even 80% is a stretch.  You can go into more complex eigenvector algorithms, but Flash doesn't have the raw computing power for that; most of the algorithms for the games you mentioned use a graphic based approach.